# Sorting dictionary descending in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am new to Python and I was wondering if there is a more common way of sorting a dictionary in descending order than the way I'm doing it:

```
sorted_dictionary = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])
```

Comment: Your approach is fine.

Comment: Is `sorted` fucntion returns anything?

Comment: @Arman the result, sorted.

Comment: Although note that dictionaries are, by definition, un-ordered. This will simply create a sorted list of tuples of key, value pairs. But I imagine you probably know that.

Comment: If you're looking for slight speed improvement then use `from operator import itemgetter; sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`.(`iteritems()` in Python 2)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a `reverse` option to `sorted()` you could use instead:

```
sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
```

This produces the exact same output, and even works if the values are not numeric.

Comment: Is it better than OP's solution?

Answer (score 8):

Python dictionary aren't sortable. Your `sorted_dictionary` output is not a dictionary but a list. You have to use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

sorted_dictionary = OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda v: v, reverse=True))
```

Comment: The OP isn't necessarily expecting a dictionary as output. They are probably fine with a list of (key, value) pairs. In other words, that the output is not actually a dictionary is *not point of the question*.

Comment: he asked to "sort a dictionary". so i was thinking he wanted a dictionary as output.

Comment: They asked if using `-` in the `lambda` is a good practice to reverse the sort.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse = True)}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sorting Dictionary based on values in ascending order**

```
d = {'a':5 , 'b':3 , 'd':1 , 'e':2 , 'f':4}
result = sorted(d.items() , key=lambda t : t[1])

for k,v in result:
  print(k,v)
```

**RESULT**

```
d 1
e 2
b 3
f 4
a 5


# d.items=[('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('d', 1), ('e', 2), ('f', 4)]
# lambda t = ('a',5)
# lambda t : t[1] = 5
# result = [('d', 1), ('e', 2), ('b', 3), ('f', 4), ('a', 5)]
# k ,v = ('d',1)
# k = 'd'  
# v = 1
```

**Sorting Dictionary based on values in descending order**

```
d = {'a':5 , 'b':3 , 'd':1 , 'e':2 , 'f':4}
result = sorted(d.items() , key=lambda t : t[1] , reverse=True)

for k,v in result:
  print(k,v)
```

**RESULT**

```
 a 5
 f 4
 b 3
 e 2
 d 1


# d.items=[('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('d', 1), ('e', 2), ('f', 4)]
# lambda t = ('a',5)
# lambda t : t[1] = 5
# result = [('a', 5), ('f', 4), ('b', 3), ('e', 2), ('d', 1)]
# k ,v = ('a',5)
# k = 'a'  
# v = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that get all the prime factors with exponents for all numbers in a range

```
    from sympy import primefactors
```

for num in range (1,10001):
    k = num
    prime_factors = {}

```
for i in primefactors(num):
    count = 0
    while num % i == 0:
        num = num/i
        count += 1
    prime_factors[i] = count  

result = sorted(prime_factors.items() , key=lambda t : t[0] , reverse=True)

count = 1
num = k

print '\n%d can be broken down into the following prime factors:' % num,
print '\n%d = ' % num,
for k,v in result:
    if count < len(result):
        print '(%d ** %d) *' % (k,v),
        count += 1
    else:
        print '(%d ** %d)' % (k,v)
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort in decreasing order of values in python list:

```
items = {'a':6 , 'b':3 , 'c':1 , 'd':9}
sortedItems = sorted(items , key=items.get , reverse = True)
for element in sortedItems :
       print (element, items.get(element))
```

Output is:

```
d 9
a 6
b 3
c 1
```